# Why the error: "InternalCompilerError: Static memory load of more than 32 bytes requested"?

Tags: struct, solidity, remix

Using Remix (https://remix.ethereum.org/) and working with struct. Compiler is `0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05`. "Optimization" was unchecked.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Test {
    struct FooBar {
        uint8 foo;
        uint16 bar;
    }

    FooBar public fooBar;

    function getFooBar() public view returns(FooBar) {
        return fooBar;
    }

    function setFooBar(FooBar value) public {
        fooBar = value;
    }
}
```

It shows an error: "InternalCompilerError: Static memory load of more than 32 bytes requested."

Not sure why. Seems to me the struct `FooBar` is only 3 bytes large. Both of my functions reads/writes a single `FooBar`. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

Refactored the code a bit to make it more clear:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Test {
    struct FooBar {
        uint8 foo;
        uint16 bar;
    }

    FooBar public fooBar;

    // InternalCompilerError: Static memory load of more than 32 bytes requested.
    function setFooBar1(FooBar value) public {
        fooBar = value;
    }

    // No such error.
    function setFooBar2(uint8 foo, uint16 bar) public {
        fooBar.foo = foo;
        fooBar.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Apparently passing the struct directly causes the compilation error, while passing in individual fields does not. Wondering what's the difference.

Comment: I know nothing about this environment, but "internal compiler error" usually means what it says: something when wrong inside the compiler: a bug. Your program may or may not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a solidity bug - see:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3361

and:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3069

also now there is a Stack Exchange for Ethereum:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @ligi. The first issue (3361) seems to be exactly what I am facing here. So, thanks for the pointer.  Duly noted about the forum. :)

Comment: Although your answer doesn't solve the problem (i.e. making the compilation error go away), I am still marking it as answered, since it points to a better page where the same question is asked and will hopefully be resolved.